# How to set global variable in Main method c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have two variables in `foreach` for username and password and I want to set to global variables but I don't know how ?
I try with this code but, when I try to replace strings with username and password with this variable I receive message:

```
Use of unsigned local variable 'username'.
Use of unsigned local variable 'password'.
```

The code:

```
            public static void Main()
        {
            string[] lineOfContents = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\M\send.txt");

            string username;
            string password;

            foreach (var line in lineOfContents)
            {
                string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
                string user = tokens[0];
                string pass = tokens[1];
                username = user;
                password = pass;
            }

            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://199.199.199.199/Plovdiv.txt");
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.  
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
```

Comment: this is because you'd initialize the variables but didn't set any value for them. You should assign an initial value for them. E.g. `string username = ""; string password = "";`

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't know whether the loop will execute or not that's why it shows such warnings, ie., The loop may or may not execute, if it skips the iteration(`lineOfContents` is null or it has no values) then your local variables `username` and `password` will not get initialized and that leads to Exceptions, to avoid that you have to initialized them with some default values, so the declaration would be like the following:

```
string username = ""; // String.Empty or some default values
string password = "";
// rest of code here
```

Answer (score 1):

You assign values to `username` and `password` inside the `foreach` loop, however the compiler doesn't know if `lineOfContents` is not empty, and when you reach to `request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);` the variables will have any value. You need to initialize them

```
string username = string.Empty;
string password = string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code has wrong logic:

1. What if `C:\M\send.txt` file is *empty*: `foreach` doesn't loop at all and `username`, `password` will contain *garbage*
2. Why do you loop over the *entire file*? It's the *last line* of the file which will be finally assigned to the `username`, `password`.

In case you want to preserve the existing logic (parse and assign the last line of the file):

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var line = File
          .ReadLines(@"C:\\M\send.txt") // We don't want All lines to be in memory
          .LastOrDefault();

        string username = ""; // or null
        string password = ""; // or null

        if (line != null)
        {
            string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
            string user = tokens[0];
            string pass = tokens[1];
            username = user;
            password = pass;
        }
        //TODO: you may want to add "else" here (i.e. the file is empty case)
```